# Каким компонентом отправить get запрос в C++ Builder6?

Tags: c++builder, cgi, c++

Суть: нужно отправить `GET` запрос на `cgi` страницу из программы на C++ Builder6. Каким компонентом лучше всего это сделать?

Может вопрос и слишком примитивный, но  все-же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если мне не изменяет память, то был компонент с названием в духе Indy HTTP Client.

Comment: спасибо, нашел в вкладке Indy Clients компонент Id HTTP.